# How can I get product details in my controller?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to fetch the product details (product id, product name) and attributes in my custom controller (`app/code/local/xxx/yyy/controllers/indexcontroller.php`). How to do that? 
I've tried:

```
$prod_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getId();
$product_name= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getName();
$productAttrs = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
```

But its not working. What to do now to fetch all these details?

Comment: what you are getting when you try this solution

Comment: I'm getting nothing, it returns blank ..!!

Comment: please show your function's code

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get id of product than you can use this

```
 $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

and for name

```
 $productName  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
```

Comment: Not working, returning 0, I want product id for current product, I think its not possible, is it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getAllData()
    {
        $prod_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getId(); 
        $product_name= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getName();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $productAttrs = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
```

Here, it is my code.

Comment: how you calling this function

Comment: With the help of button, from product view page, its a function in my controller called by different action indexAction(). Attributes values are returning, but its not returning current product.

Comment: ok, than its possible to get product details.. when you click on button than pass id in function like getAllData($id)

Comment: I am fetching the id in template now and sending it with hidden field. :)

Comment: now use this on function

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter(array(
                        array('attribute' => 'id', 'like' => '%'.$id.'%')
      
                ));